# android - read from text file line by line

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which I know that works in Java. I am now trying to do the equivalent in and Android application. The operation is quite simple: I need to make use of a method in a class (in the same workspace) where I first need to get the lines off a text file which I stored in **/res/raw**.

Basically I need to call this method residing in a Java class from an Android Activity Class. How is this possible?

Activity Class snippet (CaptureActivity.java):

```
setContentView(R.layout.orientation);
                        try {
                            SentenceGenerator sentenceGenerator = new SentenceGenerator();
                            ArrayList<String> firstState = stateGenerator.getState(resultOutput, result, result);
                            String viewPoint = firstState.get(0);
                            String object = firstState.get(1);
                            String subject = firstState.get(2);
                            Thing subjectInfo = new Thing();
                            if(resultOutput.equals("Sliema")){
                                Sliema sliema = new Sliema();
                                subjectInfo = sliema.getInfo(viewPoint, object, subject);
                            }
                            try {
                                String s = sentenceGenerator.generateSentence("start.txt", "middle.txt", "end.txt", resultOutput, viewPoint, object, subject, subjectInfo.type, subjectInfo.name, subjectInfo.properties, false);
                                TextView instructionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructionTextView);
                                instructionTextView.setText(s);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        }
```

Java Class snippet (SentenceGenerator.java):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getLines(String filename) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(strLine);
    }
    in.close();
    return lines;
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Apparently the text files are not being accessed correctly. Can I use this method to access .txt files stored in /res/raw ?

Answer (score 2):

change the following code:

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(strLine);
}
```

to

```
 Scanner br = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));
while (br.hasNext()) {
    String strLine = br.nextLine();
    lines.add(strLine);
}
```

That should work.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you user2277872 for your help. I seem to have discovered a problem which I cannot solve at the moment (see comment in original post). I will tell you if it works once I overcome this problem!